# Create real time notification like facebook in Yii

Tags: yii, notifications, yii-extensions

I am creating a web project using Yii. Is there any widget or extensions to show real time notification?
For example, I have a blog account. Any one post a comment in my post, I will get a notification and the notification counter shows in the menu without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of realtime apps online, you can create your own if you have a server that supports another port listener otherwise you can just use the following free apps like https://pusher.com/, https://app.intercom.io

Answer (score 0):

This is what i recommend  your with Yii framework

> http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-nfy/

but please check if you are working with same version and let me know once you done with your task.

Good Luck .